# MATLAB App - Add path before component creation

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I have a MATLAB App **App.mlapp** in a certain folder `~/myapp/`. The functions it uses and some graphics used in the GUI are in `~/myapp/subfolder`. In order to run **App.mlapp** correctly I have to each time manually add `~/myapp/subfolder` to my path before launching the app.

How can I automatically add the subfolder?

I tried putting `addpath(genpath(~/myapp/subfolder));` at the beginning of `StartupFcn`. However, as `StartupFcn`is called after the component creation, which already requiere some of the graphics in `~/myapp/subfolder`, this approach doesn't work. The components are created using the automatically created function `createComponents`, which cannot be edited using the App Designer Editor.

Minimal example, as requested by excaza. To create it, open the App Designer, create a new app, add a button in Design View and specify an icon in path with  *Button Properties -> Text & Icon -> More Properties -> Icon File*. Afterwards remove the directory of the icon from path and try running the app.

```
classdef app1 < matlab.apps.AppBase

    % Properties that correspond to app components
    properties (Access = public)
        UIFigure  matlab.ui.Figure
        Button    matlab.ui.control.Button
    end

    % App initialization and construction
    methods (Access = private)

        % Create UIFigure and components
        function createComponents(app)

            % Create UIFigure
            app.UIFigure = uifigure;
            app.UIFigure.Position = [100 100 640 480];
            app.UIFigure.Name = 'UI Figure';

            % Create Button
            app.Button = uibutton(app.UIFigure, 'push');
            app.Button.Icon = 'help_icon.png';
            app.Button.Position = [230 321 100 22];
        end
    end

    methods (Access = public)

        % Construct app
        function app = app1

            % Create and configure components
            createComponents(app)

            % Register the app with App Designer
            registerApp(app, app.UIFigure)

            if nargout == 0
                clear app
            end
        end

        % Code that executes before app deletion
        function delete(app)

            % Delete UIFigure when app is deleted
            delete(app.UIFigure)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you not use `addpath` right before you have to load the images? Or `cd` to your app directory and use relative paths? Please see [mcve].

Comment: @excaza I am not able to edit the `createComponents` function, which loads the custom icons (e.g. app.Help.Icon = 'help_icon.png'). MATLAB doesn't accept icons which are not in the path: I alreadfy tried specifying the Icon File as './subfolder/help_icon.png' in the App Designer Design View.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While I understand MATLAB's decision to lock away a lot of the GUI's code when designing in `appdesigner`, I've also been fairly vocal to them about the potential significant downsides, like this one.

Soapbox aside, you can get around this by exploiting MATLAB's [class property specification](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/specifying-properties.html) behavior, which initializes properties to their default properties before the rest of the class' code is executed.

In this case, we can add a dummy private variable and set it to the output of [`addpath`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html):

```
properties (Access = private)
    oldpath = addpath('./icons')
end
```

Which provides the desired behavior when passed the appropriate path.

Comment: Is there anything similar for when opening the **.mlapp* in the `app designer`? Running the app works great with your method, but if I want to edit it I still have to add the folders to `path`

Comment: [Add it to your path](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/add-remove-or-reorder-folders-on-the-search-path.html) and save it. At some point you should use the search path as it's designed.